# Clojure: when to use memoize and when to use delay/force?

Tags: clojure

I've just started learning Clojure and trying to understand the difference between 2 approaches which at first sight seem very identical.

```
(def func0 (delay (do 
                    (println "did some work") 
                    100)))
so.core=> (force my-delay2)
did some work
100
so.core=> (force my-delay2)
100
```

```
(defn vanilla-func [] (println "did some work") 100)
(def func1 (memoize vanilla-func))
so.core=> (func1)
did some work
100
so.core=> (func1)
100
```

Both approaches do some sort of function memoization. What am I missing?

I've tried to find the explanation on https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/delay & https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize but couldn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`delay` holds one result and you have to `deref` to get the result.
`memoize` is an unbound cache, that caches the result depending on the
*input arguments*.  E.g.

```clj
user=> (def myinc (memoize (fn [x] (println x) (inc x))))
#'user/myinc
user=> (myinc 1)
1
2
user=> (myinc 1)
2
```

In your (argument-less) example the only difference is that you can use
the result directly (no `deref` needed)

Classic use-cases for `delay` are things needed later, that would block
or delay startup.  Or if you want to "hide" top-level `def`s from
the compiler (e.g. they do side-effects).

`memoize` is a classic cache and is best used if the calculation is
expensive and the set of input arguments is not excessive.  There are
other caching options in the clojure-verse, that allow better
configurations (e.g. they are not unbound).

Comment: `delay` also caches exceptions unlike memoize.

Comment: What do you mean by `unbound` cache?

Comment: @Estebangs it has no limit; the items in it have no life-time. If you use above function like `(run! myinc (range))` your application will eventually run out of memory.